# Why would I use an electric bike?

Tags: electric-bike

I live in an extremely flat city that lies about 15m above sea level. One has to drive an hour or two to reach even rolling hills.

Several decades ago, I rode quite a bit, and accumulated a decent "sport touring" road bike, a mountain bike, and a track bike. Then I stopped riding for a couple decades.

Now I have returned to riding casually and found BSE, and it's full of questions about electric bikes, which didn't exist when I was riding before.

I'm healthy for my age. When I ride, I want to be burning all the calories I can. My commute is only 3-4 km. Why would I want an e-bike? What advantages do they offer?

Comment: I searched for this question because I couldn't believe it didn't exist already. If it does, please flag this one as a dup.

Comment: Because steam-powered bikes are such a pain to operate.

Comment: I think the advantages should be obvious. You can go further or faster, for less effort. If those advantages are contrary to your goals, you probably *don't* want one. They're considerably heavier and more expensive.

Comment: Also, if you are fit enough, you can easily go 25 km/h on a normal bike, which is the max support speed for many E-bikes (most in my country, at least, and the once that have higher support, well, they are not bikes, they are motorbikes, imho). Once you reach this speed, the motor just won't help anymore. So, for fit people like myself, an E-bike would just make those 25 km/h feel like a wall: No effort biking below it, full effort above it. That's not a very attractive thought to me, so I will stay with 100% human power. It's better for the environment anyway.

Comment: @shoover you expected someone else to wonder why _you_ should use an electric bike?

Comment: @cmaster I briefly considered a 250W kit and fairly small battery because a certain hill would have knocked over 10% off a possible 20km commute. An e-bike has had that effect for someone I know, making daily bike commuting possible in the available time. In the end I didn't get that job and now don't think much of the hill or distance either, so it would have been a waste.

Comment: So far I'm getting some good responses. I think I know which one I'll accept as "the" answer, but I'll give people another day to answer before I choose one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't (yet) own an E-Bike, but have spoken to my LBS a few times to find out whats happening in the market. My interest is Mountain biking more than road riding, but the observations probably apply more or less to the same extent.

1) People who are less fit / non-cyclists get into riding who otherwise would not. This does not appear to apply to you.

2) In many cases price competitive to non-electric bike - I had trouble taking this seriously then had it explained. People go into a bike shop looking for a bike to lighten their wallet. Evey cyclists knows you quickly get into the $/gram game and end up spending hundreds to save a few grams. Many buyers then turn to the E-Bike rack, and work out they could have a 'decent enough' e-bike made with mid range components for around the price of the light weight racer they are looking at.

3) Further and longer translates to more fun for the same effort. A recurring theme is cyclists on E-Bikes head out and ride for longer - 4 hours instead of 2, 8 hours instead of 6. The main reason is they are still enjoying riding at the end of a long day because they have not worn themselves out.

4) Diverse groups - many people worry they are the one holding everyone up, and do not wants to be 'that guy'  (or girl). Rather than join a group they don't ride. A recent event some mates did was a 70km, 2 day MTB ride with a diverse group from diehard's to tag along partners who struggle with 20km rides.  The less fit/confident/skilled in the group rode E-Bikes. The end result was the group rode together, stopped and rested together and no one felt pressured or held up. The ride converted some hardcore 'Box before E-Bike' types to 'Not till I am old and slow'

5) Fitness - evidence is building that people who buy E-Bikes gain more fitness than those buying traditional bikes, because they ride more often and longer. I suspect there is an element of the starting point of many E-Bike riders is very low.

Everyone is different - me, 20 years ao, would have lef tthe E-Bike on teh rack. Now over 50, if buying a new bike, my ego says its too soon.... Couple of long hard rides I might get it to change its mind.

Comment: E-MTBs are an interesting case, making riding much more fun for some people whose skill exceeds their fitness. I'm the other way round (lack of skill but road fit) and we can enjoy riding trails together with decent sustained climbs. I've also seen one old on-road model that according to its original owner kept him off a mobility scooter for a decade by allowing short trips to be made at low effort.

Comment: This looks like a good list of reasons for getting (or not getting) an e-bike.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm healthy for my age. When I ride, I want to be burning all the calories I can. My commute is only 3-4 km. Why would I want an e-bike?

You probably wouldn't. E-bikes are for helping you go farther or faster<sup>*</sup> than you could on your own. Since you don't seem to need that, an e-bike doesn't seem to have any advantage for you.

<sup>*</sup> In most countries, e-bikes have to cut out the assistance at around 25km/h (16mph) so "faster" only applies if you're cyling slower than that.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an e-bike. But some acquantances do or do/did think about getting one:

- One lives in a flat region as well, and tries to convert from car-driving to work to e-biking. Emphasis is on not arriving sweaty (possibility to change, but not to shower), but still in a reasonable time.
  So, no reason for you.
- One other acquantance who was thinking about an e-bike lives in a hilly region with the "flattest" possibility to get to work being 150 m elevation gain (half of that in a steep ascend just before arriving) and 225 m elevation gain on the way back.
  I do see far more e-bikes in hilly regions. Again, no reason for you.
- I've been living with 150 m difference in elevation from work for a couple of years, but fortunately that was almost exclusively down in the morning and up on the way home. The thought of an e-bike was somewhat tempting, but not that much: if I didn't feel like the 20 % incline on the usual way, there was another (longer) way that didn't require that much residual will power after long working days (or a party).
- I've heard as an argument for e-bike: in urban settings, bikers (just as everyone else) have to stop frequently, and get going again. This acceleration is the annoying and power-consuming part of biking in cities (particularly if you carry kids and possibly groceries around). An e-bike may help with that.
  Don't know whether that could be a reason for you, probably not, though, if your emphasis is on maximising *your* energy output.

Answer (score 3):

I had an e-bike conversion - it was a replacement front wheel with a hub motor, and a battery pack in the main triangle.

After a year I sold the kit on - the bike was simply too fast, and I wasn't getting the exercise.  Plus I was smashing through strava KOMs which wasn't really fair to those who worked hard.

Another negative for that conversion was that a fat rider on an old 90s steel MTB shouldn't be going 45 km/h, and cars would routinely pull out in front of me, or open car doors.  **Also**, the bike's cantilever brakes were not really specified or rated for hauling down 30 kilos of bike plus a hundred kilos of rider and whatever I was moving.  Brake pads lasted a couple of months tops.

The final straw was general traction.  On any slightly damp day I got wheel spin when accelerating - the pedal action unweighted the front wheel and made it loose traction.  The bike was incredibly keen to slip sideways, especially if I came into a turn or corner a bit fast (which was often)  And while I never fell or had a collision, there were multiple times I took a corner too fast and ended up on the wrong side of the road.  Some of that was doubtless my... enthusiasm for going fast, which could have been unlearned.

So an ebike makes riding easier and less work, which is less exercise overall.  For me, riding faster than others was the attraction, but it wore off over time and now I ride a road bike and a recumbent bike faster and further than that electrified one.

Question really becomes - why do **you** ride ?

Comment: Good point about traffic not anticipating your speed, do you mean “shouldn’t” or “wouldn’t normally” be goingthat speed?

Comment: @Swifty I was certainly pedalling for it, and the extra 300W got me to those high speeds.  I missed a point about brakes, adding now.

Comment: Strava has a specific activity you can select as E-Bike ride which should stop you from knocking others off the KOM for regular bike rides.

Comment: @Kibbee back in 2014 that was not an option - they only supported run/ride/walk at that point.

Comment: I can not imagine a bike being too fast. "After a year I sold the kit on - the bike was simply too fast, and I wasn't getting the exercise." :-)

Comment: @fixit7 as per edits - the brakes were not specced for that kind of stopping, and I found drivers could underestimate my oncoming speed and pull out when there wasn't room.  Thus "too fast"

Answer (score 3):

Each of the responses to your question addresses the OP's particular situation and concerns, i.e., recreation and fitness. However, someone discovering this question is probably asking themselves "Why should I?", so I'll try to speak to them. In short, **you should use an electric bike to get a carectomy**.

The [now-defunct website carectomy.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20080701064634/http://www.carectomy.com/) introduced me years ago to this concept:  the painful but ultimately satisfying process of extracting cars from people.

E-bikes were key to getting my carectomy. My e-bike helped me, as a car-bound commuter, [evaluate the time/money/carbon footprint tradeoff on investment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46956/how-do-you-measure-return-on-investment-roi-for-an-electric-bike), all in order to play a trick on myself. I purchased nice saddlebags, rain gear, and a nice bike to put myself in a position where I could make no excuses about biking to work. On warm, sunny days, riding instead of driving was easy. On rainy days, it was less easy but tolerable with gear. On frigid days, the combined cost of the gear and bike, as well as not having a car to fall back on, forced me to bike anyway. All this makes trips to the store etc. trivial when compared to a commute, and suddenly, my carectomy is complete.

Folks browsing Stack Exchange Bicycles often ride for health, sport, and similar reasons, evaluating technique and gear choices, for example. Yet the true target market of e-bikes isn't bikers, it's people who need a carectomy. If the question is "Why would I use an electric bike?", I offer that you would use it as a lever to change your behavior and get that carectomy you always needed.

Comment: +1 for "carectomy"

Answer (score 3):

> I live in an extremely flat city that lies about 15m above sea level. One has to drive an hour or two to reach even rolling hills.
>
> Several decades ago, I rode quite a bit, and accumulated a decent "sport touring" road bike, a mountain bike, and a track bike. Then I stopped riding for a couple decades.
>
> Now I have returned to riding casually and found BSE, and it's full of questions about electric bikes, which didn't exist when I was riding before.
>
> I'm healthy for my age. When I ride, I want to be burning all the calories I can. My commute is only 3-4 km. Why would I want an e-bike? What advantages do they offer?

There is practically no advantage for a 3-4 km commute in a non-hilly region.

I have found that the most benefit electric bike offers is that:

- It helps tremendously when going up hills
- It helps when starting from traffic lights -- if there are a lot of traffic lights in your non-hilly city, you could perhaps benefit from an electric bike but otherwise don't
- It helps you after you become tired, so longer distances are feasible, but of course then the battery life starts to be eaten rapidly
- It allows you to always use a high gear even though you might need to occasionally start moving at a slight incline

My electric road bike helps me only when starting from traffic lights and going up hills. It normally does not help in flat terrain because the 25 km/h limit of the electric assist is reached even with no electric assist. However when I become really tired, then the e-bike starts to help also in a flat terrain.

I stopped riding for 5 years and now I resumed riding with two e-bikes, an e-fatbike and an e-roadbike. I'm not completely healthy for my age as I'm somewhat overweight, which is quite annoying when going up hills. An e-bike helps in that.

Don't buy an e-bike unless your commute is full of traffic lights. Or, if there are reasonably many traffic lights with slight incline after them, and you absolutely hate gear changes, then you could also benefit from an e-bike allowing you to avoid those gear changes.